# gatsbyJS Link: want to use backticks in to property, but cannot

Tags: hyperlink, gatsby

I want to write something like this in my Gatsbyjs Link tag:

```
 <Link to=`/${this.props.latestPost.node.slug}`>Click Here</Link>
```

but it's not working, and my code looks like this:

[image]

Is there some way I could use a javascript expression inside the 'to' property? I want the slug to be dynamic, as the Link tag is for a 'recent posts' set of links, that will regularly update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape it as Javascript:

```babel
<Link to={`/${this.props.latestPost.node.slug}`}>Click Here</Link>
```